# XSLT expand-text="yes" causes extra whitespace in the output

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, saxon, xslt-3.0

Setting expand-text="yes" in an XSLT stylesheet appears to cause extra whitespace to be emitted in the output XML. For example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    expand-text="no"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output `AB`. But if I change it to `expand-text="yes"` then it produces `A B`.

Can anyone help explain this behavior? Is it by design? I am using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7.

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: I have tried the example with `expand-text="yes"` in Exselt and the output is `AB`. I am not sure which result is correct although https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stylesheet-stripping does not seem to indicate any relation between the whitespace stripping and `expand-text`.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Saxon 9.7 gets this right, Saxon 9.6 got it wrong. It was evaluating the xsl:text element as a string rather than as a text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness: this was a bug in Saxon 9.6 that is fixed in 9.7.